# Word length and substitute using sed - bash

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a file that looks like this:

```
hell hi tell smith david
abc def ab abcd 
123456 123ab
```

I would like to reverse all the words with length 3 and 4, to get output like this:

```
lleh hi llet smith david    
cba fed ac abcd
123456 123ab
```

How can I do that using strictly only `sed`?

Comment: Your example has words of length 4 reversed as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
sed -re 's/\<(.)(.)(.)\>/\3\2\1/g'
```

Explanation:

- The `-r` flag is to be able to use extended regular expressions. It's specific to GNU sed. Without this, I would have to write the pattern as: `\<\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\>`
- `\<` matches beginning of a word, and `\>` the end. Both have zero length.
- Things matched within `(...)` can be used in the replacement as `\1` for the first expression, `\2` for the second `(...)`, and so on.
- The `g` flag at the end is to replace all occurances on the same line, not only the first

In short, the search pattern matches words of length 3, and replaces them with their letters reversed.

I see you updated your example, and you want to reverse words with length 4 too. To do that you can add another expression following the same logic, like this:

```
sed -re 's/\<(.)(.)(.)\>/\3\2\1/g' -e 's/\<(.)(.)(.)(.)\>/\4\3\2\1/g'
```

Comment: Thank a lot. There is a problem with the first word (hell), it wont reverse.

Comment: @DavidLesner I updated my answer to handle that case too, see at the end.

Comment: Thanks again. I wasn't familiar with the '-re' flag.

Comment: @DavidLesner if you edit your question with examples of what you tried and didn't work, or things that confused you, then there's a chance your question might get reopened and even upvoted. But only if you do it right.